# $p$ and $r$ are primes greater than $2$. $p+r$ vs $p+2r$, which could be a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

For $p+2r$, a example would be $3$ and $5$. Since $6+5 = 11$, I am led to believe $p+2r$ to be the right answer. But I don't know how it works?

Comment: You need to find a divisor  for $p+r$. Look at your example. What is the smallest (non trivial) divisor of $3+5$ ?

Comment: i guess it doesn't work as 7+2*13=33

Comment: @Nemo, it says "could be". Also both have to be larger than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $p+r > 2$ and is an even number.

Comment: I thought all even number bigger than 2 are composite?

Comment: That's the point. :-)

Comment: Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: But how do you know there isn't a prime number that's the sum of the other two prime number?

Comment: Take $p = 5, q = 7$ for the other one.

Comment: Ok I finally got it. Because any prime number than 2 is odd. So their sum must be even.